# How would I mount a linux shared folder on another linux system?

Tags: linux, samba, webserver, file-sharing, web

What I'm trying to do is to share my VM development web server's /www folder, to make it more convenient to transfer the HTML, PHP and web documents I have made to test on the web server.

Would I have to use Samba to do this? Or would there be a simpler solution since I am using Linux-Linux.

Comment: On a Linux-Linux environment, a better solution could be NFS: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-ubuntu-nfs-server-configuration-howto/

Comment: `sshfs`. Then all you need is `sshd` on the server which you probably already have.

Comment: You can use Midnight Commander to work with local and remote filesystems through `ssh` in two panes. In `mc`: `cd sh://your_server` and you're done.

Answer (score 7):

If you're looking for something light and easy to setup [sshfs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS) is by far the easiest to set up. Sshfs mounts remote directories through ssh and presents them as locally mounted directories & files. It sounds more complicated than it actually works out to be.

First make sure that you have sshfs installed on the system where you'll be wanting to create mounts. For example, say I have my laptop and a remote server. I'd install `sshfs` on my laptop so that I can mount directories locally on it, from the remote server.

#### Example

```
$ sshfs sam@skinner:/home/sam/docs ~/far_projects

$ ls -l ~/far_projects/
total 1260
drwxr-x--- 1 5060 users   4096 Mar 30  2004 acronyms
drwxr-xr-x 1 5060 users   4096 Nov 16  2008 articles
drwxr-xr-x 1 5060 users   4096 Nov 16  2008 bookmark_repository
drwxr-xr-x 1 5060 users   4096 Oct 14  2009 books
drwxr-xr-x 1 5060 users   4096 Nov 15  2008 cheatsheets
-rw-r--r-- 1 5060 users   6855 Feb 19  2009 cheatsheet.txt
```

When you're done with the mount you can use the command `fusermount` to unmount it.

```
$ fusermount -u ~/far_projects
$ ls ~/far_projects/
$
```

These types of mounts can even be integrated into `/etc/fstab`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NFS export to share a folder

On your Linux Server_1 where you want to share a folder do the following:

```
   echo /shared_folder *(rw,sync) >> /etc/exports

   /etc/init.d/nfs restart
```

Do the following on your linux server_2 where you need to mount the shared folder from server_1:

```
   mkdir /shared_folder

   mount -t nfs Server_1:/shared_folder /shared_folder
```